# How to calculate this multivariable limit?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$
\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0) } \frac{\sin(x^2+y^2+z^2) + \tan(x+y+z) }{|x|+|y|+|z|}
$$

I know the entire limit should not exist. In addition, the limit:
$$
\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0) } \frac{\tan(x+y+z) }{|x|+|y|+|z|}
$$
does not exist and it seems like the limit:
$$
\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0) } \frac{\sin(x^2+y^2+z^2) }{|x|+|y|+|z|}
$$
is zero. But, how can I calculate this limit (the last one) ?

Will you please help me?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{|x|+|y|+|z|}=\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{|x|+|y|+|z|}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. The first factor tends to $1$, the second is bounded and the last tends to zero.

---

To answer your question in your comment:

$$x^2+y^2+z^2\leq x^2+y^2+z^2+2|x||y|+2|x||z|+2|y||z|=(|x|+|y|+|z|)^2$$

Therefore $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{|x|+|y|+|z|}\leq1$$

> A good-to-know fact is that the norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are all equivalent. $\|(x,y,z)\|_2=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ and $\|(x,y,z)\|_1=|x|+|y|+|z|$ are to norms of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and equivalence means that there are non-zero constants $c,C$ such that
>
> $$c\|\cdot\|_1\leq \|\cdot\|_2\leq C\|\cdot\|_1$$
> In our case $C=1$.

Comment: Why is the second one bounded?

Comment: @CrazyStatistician Answered above.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to proceed is to transform variables to spherical coordinates.

To that end, let $x=r \sin \theta \cos \phi$, $y=r\sin \theta \sin \phi$, and $z=r\cos \theta$, where $0\le \theta \le \pi$ and $0\le \phi \le 2\pi$.  Then, the limit that is in question is

$$\lim_{r\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin r^2}{r(|\sin \theta \cos \phi|+|\sin \theta \sin \phi|+|\cos \theta|)}\right)=0$$

To see this, note that

$$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\sin r^2}{r} =0,$$

which can be shown using L'Hospital's Rule.  It is important to note that for all $0\le \theta \le \pi$ and $0\le \phi \le 2\pi$, $1\le|\sin \theta \cos \phi|+|\sin \theta \sin \phi|+|\cos \theta| \le \sqrt{3}$ is bounded.

---

Now, for the entire problem, we need to examine the limit

$$\lim_{r\to 0} \left(\frac{\sin r^2+\tan (r(\sin \theta \cos \phi +\sin \theta \sin \phi + \cos \theta))}{r(|\sin \theta \cos \phi|+|\sin \theta \sin \phi|+|\cos \theta|)}\right)$$

Clearly, the limit as $r \to 0$ does not exist inasmuch as its value depends on the values of $\theta$ and $\phi$.  For example, if $\theta =0$, then the limit is $1$ since $\sin \theta \cos \phi +\sin \theta \sin \phi + \cos \theta = 1$, $|\sin \theta \cos \phi|+|\sin \theta \cos \phi|+|\cos \theta| =1$ and

$$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\sin r^2}{r} =0$$

$$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\tan r}{r} = 1$$

which can be easily shown by using L'Hospital's Rule.  This first limit is, in fact, the limit that was in question.

If $\theta = \pi$, then the limit is $-1$ since $\sin \theta \cos \phi +\sin \theta \sin \phi + \cos \theta = -1$, $|\sin \theta \cos \phi|+|\sin \theta \cos \phi|+|\cos \theta| =1$ and

$$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\sin r^2}{r} =0$$

$$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\tan (-r)}{r} = -1$$

Inasmuch as the limit is non-unique, it does not exist.

Comment: Nice! ThAnks!!!

Comment: Thank you!  And you're quite welcome!  My pleasure.  I hope that this equips you with another tool that you can use going forward.